# Autocomplete words in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, typeahead

I want a solution where in my textarea, I can write the text with autocomplete feature. The solution should be similar to writing in an editor, where I can go back and add new word if I want and it should suggest autocomplete for that too.

I have tried few examples, but none seem to be working for my problem. The closest example I got is https://bl.ocks.org/wheresjames/9643ce9d0a83ef30b36fc16d5a18e0ac

But this solution has few problems. 
For instance: 
1. Its not working with ng-model
2. Clicking outside the box seems to change the value of textbox to last selected autocomplete.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using mdAutocomplete and it works great!

> mdAutocomplete is a special input component with a drop-down of all
>   possible matches to a custom query. This component allows you to
>   provide real-time suggestions as the user types in the input area.

[Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)

[DEMO](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

Comment: I think OP is asking about angularjs, not angular2.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The fact that angular and angularjs docs have similar styles is so confusing.

Comment: Hi regarding mdAutocomplete, the demos shown are only for single autocomplete. However, I want to have feature where I can write as many number of words as I want, and it shows autocomplete for each word I am currently typing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CodeMirror? It has support for [autocompletion](http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html), [integration with angularjs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror) and [plugins to support your own dictionary](https://github.com/amarnus/ng-codemirror-dictionary-hint).